# angular-google-maps API key from backend

Tags: angularjs, angularfire, angular-google-maps

Generally, this question is about how to use some dynamic content from a backend inside a module.config function in AngularJS.

Specifically, this question is regarding the GoogleMapApi provider in [angular-google-maps](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps)

In my Angular Application the Google Maps API key is stored in a Firebase backend. What I would like to do is to set the API key for the GoogleMapApiProvider

```
.config(function(uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
    uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
    key: 'your api key',
    }); 
})
```

I know that I only have Providers and Constants available in the Angular module config function. So I struggle to think of a way to get the necessary API key from my Firebase backend using the [$firebaseProvider](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/index.html)
Any help or direction is most appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Is this a per-user key that you're pulling from Firebase? or a common shared key? (I'm trying to understand why it needs to live in Firebase.)

Comment: It is per user. The user authenticates with his firebase  account and receives his API key for the angularjs frontend

Comment: In that case I think you may not be able to do this in the "configuration" stage... I'm not familiar enough with the library to say for sure, but I'd suspect this would work as a service..

Comment: @JanTeichmann, so, hat was your solution to this problem finally?

Comment: @JanTeichmann did you manage to get this working? I have same issue.