# How to pass the variables to AngularJs config

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I work with [AngularJS Google Maps](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/) and need to configure the `api_key` in the module `config` part (question similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327778/angular-google-maps-api-key-from-backend)).

My question is about configuring AngularJs modules

This is [my test pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYeGbN?editors=101):

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', [])
  /* 
     // HERE ????? 
     // I try to pass a value from the HTML (server side)

  .config(function($window){
    console.log($window.memKey);
  }) 

  */
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
    $scope.name = $window.memName;
    $scope.city = $window.memCity;

    $scope.getMember = function(id) {
      console.log(id);
    };
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var memKey = 'bb7de28f-0f89-4f14-8575-d494203acec7';
  var memName = 'John';
  var memCity = 'New-York';
</script>   

<div  ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  Member name: {{name}} <br>
  Member city: {{city}}
</div>
```

How is possible to recuperate the `memKey` value from the HTML (Server) side?

Answer (score 1):

your memKey is in an accesible scope, according on how you've declared it.

just do

```
 app.config(function(){
    console.log(memKey);
  })
```

See [snippet](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyLwpr?editors=101)

Comment: magic! you are right... now is there a more "correct" way to ***pass*** values to the config function

Comment: you can pass providers to the config functions, where they can be services, values or constants. The last two could be useful for you. See https://gist.github.com/demisx/9605099 for description or each one, and then see which one suits more for you. Probably a constant. You can then use them as parameters in config function

Comment: should the "configuratle" column mean that they are not available in the `.config` because examples are on the controllers, not on the config functions...

Comment: they are examples, you can inject them in the config as well

Answer (score 1):

You can access an existing angular module if you don't use the injection array. After you have the reference, you can declare constants eg:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var app = angular.module('myapp');  
 app.constant('memKey', 'bb7de28f-0f89-4f14-8575-d494203acec7');
 app.constant('memName', 'John');
 app.constant('memCity', 'New-York');
 //Or do them as one config object
</script>
```

--

```
  .config(['memKey', 'memName','memCity'  function(memKey, memName, memCity) {
  }]);
```

Comment: attention. The values should be used not in the **`.controller`**, but in the **`.config`** part

Comment: You can inject constants into config, they're initialized first. Updated my answer to reflect your actual question.

Comment: Codepen is loading angular after the HTML tags scrips are done, so that's breaking. Also, don't wrap the constants in a load event, it's not needed.

Comment: this time updated with really a literal constant, still another error: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYeGbN?editors=101

Comment: It's just a timing thing with codepen and angular getting loaded, see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaGymm?editors=101 . I added the constant definitions to the JS pane. They just need to be included after the angular.js include, and after your module is initial declared.

Comment: Yeah... seems to work better in JSFiddle, when loading angular in the head section... http://jsfiddle.net/r9oeuvgp/